# ¿Como variar el valor de varias celdas de una matríz con un lazo "for" en MATLAB/MATPOWER?

Tags: array, matlab, matrices-asociativas

mi problema es este, tengo una matríz "mpc.bus" 4x4 en MATPOWER y dos vectores:

```
A=[2.7 2.1 2.4]

B=[0.8 1.0 0.9]
```

Quiero variar los valores de las celdas de la matríz de la siguiente manera:

```
mpc.bus(fila2, columna2)=A(1:3)

mpc.bus(fila2, columna3)=B(1:3)
```

Evaluando la matriz 3 veces de forma que:

```
mpc.bus(2,2)=A(1) entonces mpc.bus(2,3)=B(1) 

mpc.bus(2,2)=A(2) entonces mpc.bus(2,3)=B(2)

mpc.bus(2,2)=A(2) entonces mpc.bus(2,3)=B(3)
```

al utilizar un lazo for tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
for i=A(1:3);  
for j=B(1:3);



mpc.bus(2, 2)=i;

   mpc.bus(2, 3)=j;

runpf(mpc);    
end
end
```

Esta es la única forma en que he logrado que corra el programa, pero está variando todas las combinaciones de los vectores de la forma:

```
mpc.bus(2,2)=A(1) entonces mpc.bus(2,3)=B(1)

mpc.bus(2,2)=A(1) entonces mpc.bus(2,3)=B(2)

mpc.bus(2,2)=A(1) entonces mpc.bus(2,3)=B(3)
```

Y repite las evaluaciones de todos los valores de B para cada valor de A... realizando un total de 9 evaluaciones.

¿Alguien sabe como hacer para que el programa evalúe la matríz de la forma deseada?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que A y B tengan siempre el mismo tamaño:

```
for i=1:length(A)  
   mpc.bus(2, 2)=A(i);
   mpc.bus(2, 3)=B(i);    
   runpf(mpc);    
end
```